# Electron - Smooth animated switching between screens in main window

Tags: javascript, electron

I can find a few thousand examples of creating new windows with electron, and how to change out the current main windows to a new file, But I'm really stumped when it comes to being able to smoothly transition between pages.

I could build all the functionality into the index and swap it out, but that seems overly complex and load heavy.
I could use one of the react bootstraps but this seems rather heavy on learning and counter intuitive to Electron (Plus a massive amount of messing around with multiple package loaders and other such things I've seen).
I've seen some things in the docs for child windows and seem someone suggest the use of those, or hidden windows to pre-load content, append onto the existing page, animate then remove the old. But that just sounds like a nightmare when it comes to adding event listeners.

I just need a way to be able to transition nicely between say a splash page and a load page, then the app page
Then say in the app transition in a modal

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use multiple windows and if the user clicks on the close button for one of them I do not perform a `window.close()` but a hide(). In addition on every close button press I check if at least one window is left to keep the app alive. If not I exit the application. For ipc calls I introduced a naming convention like: "settings_win-operation1", "splash_win-operation1" and so forth.